# How to enter values in an interactive command line process in Java?

Tags: java, shell

If I call a command line process like this:

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("foo -bar");
InputStream in = proc.getInputStream();
InputStream err = proc.getErrorStream();
```

How do I enter values in it if it's interactive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `proc.getOutputStream()` to obtain an `OutputStream` to which you can write the shell script inputs.